# the merge in git-flow

Tags: git, git-flow

There's a main branch called master, and I create new one called dev basic on master, basic on dev, there're three files in branch dev as following

a file with content `123456`
b file with content `34567`
c file with content `09783`

I create another two branches basic on branch dev for two developers, one is called dev1, another is called dev2, each branch has the some files and contents with dev, and now dev1 change the a file's content to `2345`, and commit & push to dev1(remote), and merge to dev, at the same time, dev2 change the b file's content to `87829`, and commit, and now dev2 wants to get dev1's changes, he do some steps as following

```
git checkout dev
git pull
git checkout dev2
git rebase dev
```

yes, dev2 can get the dev1's change, here is the new a file's content `2345`, but his b file's content is changed to `34567`, not `87829` not he changed and commited's content, so which step am i wrong? thanks

Comment: Please add complete command history. This is hard to follow.